# What is wrong with the if else if else statement in this C# script?

Tags: c#, if-statement, equality

I am having trouble with a C# script that uses the Sony Vegas Pro scripting API to generate an edit list of video clips for trimming in ffmpeg. The full script and details of the purpose can be found at [http://www.sonycreativesoftware.com/forums/showmessage.asp?forumid=21&messageid=932542](http://www.sonycreativesoftware.com/forums/showmessage.asp?forumid=21&messageid=932542%20%22here%22.).

Part of my script is shown below. When I run the script I get the error *"The name 'OffsetAdjusterFrames' does not exist in the current context"*, relating to the line `Timecode OffsetAdjuster = Timecode.FromFrames(OffsetAdjusterFrames);` , and *"The name 'DurationAdjusterFrames' does not exist in the current context"* relating to the next line.

The problem seems to be with the line `if (clipOffsetOriginalFrames == 0)` or with something else in that `if else if else` statement. If I bypass the whole of that `if else if else` statement by commenting it out and explicitly declaring `OffsetAdjusterFrames` and `DurationAdjusterFrames` then the rest of the script works.

Any help would be appreciated as I have run out of things to try. Thanks.

Edit: This is different to [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650187/scope-error-in-if-statement-in-java-program) because this is C# and that is Java, so it's not really a duplicate, but the general solution is the same.

```
...
    Timecode clipOffsetOriginal = videoEvent.ActiveTake.Offset;
    // clipOffsetOriginal as a number of frames
    Int64 clipOffsetOriginalFrames = videoEvent.ActiveTake.Offset.FrameCount;

    Timecode clipOffset = clipOffsetOriginal - startAdd;
    Timecode clipDuration = videoEvent.Length + startAdd + endAdd;

    // Reset start to zero if start was not trimmed at all, and compensate length
    if (clipOffsetOriginalFrames == 0)
    {
        int OffsetAdjusterFrames = 2;
        int DurationAdjusterFrames = -2;
    }
    // Reset start to zero if start had been trimmed by just 1 frame, and compensate length
    else if (clipOffsetOriginalFrames == 1)
    {
        int OffsetAdjusterFrames = 1;
        int DurationAdjusterFrames = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        int OffsetAdjusterFrames = 0;
        int DurationAdjusterFrames = 0;
    }

    Timecode OffsetAdjuster = Timecode.FromFrames(OffsetAdjusterFrames);
    Timecode DurationAdjuster = Timecode.FromFrames(DurationAdjusterFrames);
    Timecode clipOffsetAdjusted = clipOffset + OffsetAdjuster;
    Timecode clipDurationAdjusted = clipDuration + DurationAdjuster;

    // Convert start and duration from timecode to seconds
    double start = clipOffsetAdjusted.ToMilliseconds() / 1000;
            double duration = clipDurationAdjusted.ToMilliseconds() / 1000;

    string triminfo = String.Format(basename + ".mp4 " + start + " " + duration);
...
```

Comment: Thank you @mmking. I didn't find that question because it refers to Java rather than C#. I didn't realise the solution would also apply in general to C#.

Comment: Oops sorry. I screwed up. But in general, Java and C# work more or less the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables `OffsetAdjusterFrames` and `DurationAdjusterFrames` are declared inside the if statement, so they are local variables and can't be called from outside your if statements.

When you move the declaration outside of the if statement, say into the method, it works because the scope of the variable is in the method, so can be called outside of the if statement as long as it's within the method.

---

So basically just declare the variables at the start of the method, like this:

```
int OffsetAdjusterFrames;
int DurationAdjusterFrames;
```

and then assign the values in your if statements like this:

```
// Reset start to zero if start was not trimmed at all, and compensate length
if (clipOffsetOriginalFrames == 0)
{
    OffsetAdjusterFrames = 2;
    DurationAdjusterFrames = -2;
}
// Reset start to zero if start had been trimmed by just 1 frame, and compensate length
else if (clipOffsetOriginalFrames == 1)
{
    OffsetAdjusterFrames = 1;
    DurationAdjusterFrames = -1;
}
else
{
    OffsetAdjusterFrames = 0;
    DurationAdjusterFrames = 0;
}
```